# vb.net check if two panels are overlapping

Tags: vb.net, panel

I have a panel that I can move around with a drag/drop system. I would like it to snap to a certain position when it is drug on top of another panel. How would I check if the panels are overlapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply check if panels are overlapping, use [Rectangle.IntersectsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you need to know **how** exactly they are overlapping, use [Rectangle.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In both cases you need to be using [Panel.Bounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as arguments, so either

```
Dim b As Boolean = panel1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)
```

or

```
Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangle.Intersect(panel1.Bounds, panel2.Bounds)
```

Then check if `r` is large enough for drag and drop, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check if panels are overlapping, you can check if panel bounds overlap:

```
Dim arePanelsOverlapping = panel1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(panel2.Bounds)
```

To snap to the position, you can also make use of `Top`, `Left`, `Bottom` and `Right` properties.